# Why this output of this C program?

Tags: c

Program:

```
   int main( )
    {
    printf("%d",printf("%d %d",5,5)&printf("%d %d",7,7));
    return 0;
    }
```

Output:

```
5 57 73
```

I am new to C, I could guess where the 5 57 7 came from, but no idea where the 3 came from. Can someone explain the output?

Comment: This type of code is what gives C a bad name...

Comment: Be aware that `7 75 53` would be a valid outcome, too, as `&` is no sqeuence point (c.f. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you apply binary `AND` to `3` and `3` (which are the return values of both nested `printf` calls) you get `3` as result.

Note that the code actually contains undefined behaviour, since the order of the nested calls isn't defined.

Comment: Do you mean *unspecified behavior* instead of *undefined behavior*?

Comment: @ouah To be honest, I'm too lazy to look it up.

Comment: It's unspecified, I think. "An example of unspeciﬁed behavior is the order in which the arguments to a function are evaluated.", I'm pretty sure that operators are like functions in that respect.

Answer (score 6):

The return value of the `printf` function is the number of characters transmitted, or a negative value if there is an error.

`printf("%d %d",5,5)` returns `3` if there is no error

`printf("%d %d",7,7)` also returns `3` if there is no error

So `printf("%d %d",5,5) & printf("%d %d",7,7)` is `3 & 3` which is evaluated to `3`.

Comment: Why does printf("%d %d",5,5) returns 3?

Comment: @AshwinSingh Because that is what `printf` returns. The number of printed characters.

Answer (score 2):

3 is the [Bitwise AND](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) of the values returned by two printf.

printf returns the numbers of characters printed. 
In your case, `printf("%d %d",5,5)` has printed three characters that are two 5 and one space, similarly `printf("%d %d",7,7)` is also printing two 7 and one space. Hence both printf is returning 3.

so, 3 is the result of `3 & 3`

Answer (score 0):

as you can see here : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string, printf return the number of printed chars, so:

```
printf("%d",printf("%d %d",5,5)&printf("%d %d",7,7));
```

is composed of :

```
printf("%d %d",5,5) return 3 (5 space and 5) and print 5 5

printf("%d %d",7,7) return 3 (7 space and 7) and print 7 7
```

At this stage we got : `5 57 7`

And `3 & 3 = 3`, finally you got this output:

```
5 57 73
```

Regards.